How to get rid of devtools hint in input autofill in Chrome
Recently when I'm working with inputs in React / Javascript and I click into the inputs to type stuff like address etc, Chrome opens up this strange context menu which is unwanted by me. Is there a way to disable this? I've tried turning autofill off in Chrome settings (Autofill and passwords) but it doesn't help.

